# PHP Switch Between Multiple Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I already create php file to load the data from database (db1). There are more than 10 database separate at different location and settings (like host, user, pass and db_name). Using the same php code, I want to switch beetwen database (using 1 connection file).

Here is the connection.php :

```
<?php
$db_host = "192.152.8.2";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "toor";
$db_name = "db1";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Database Connection Failed : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

$db_host2 = "192.152.9.5";
$db_user2 = "root";
$db_pass2 = "rooter";
$db_name2 = "db2";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_pass2, $db_name2);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Database Connection Failed : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Here is the controller:

```
<?php

$db = @new MySQLi ("$db_host","$db_user","$db_pass","$db_name");
$db->connect_errno and die('Koneksi database gagal: '.$db->connect_error);

//Query the data

$res = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from student where ipSemId='".$ipSemId."'")
or die($db->error);

?>
```

Right now, I make it manually (by changing the $db variable). Is there other ways to make it simple (maybe using if..else)? Need a suggestion, please. Thanks.

Comment: What determines which db to connect to? If it's an ordinal value or unique string, you could use a simple switch / case statement.

Comment: the php codes only once but it will load the db1 when visiting link1 and than it will load db2 when visiting link2. Is that possible?

Comment: With programming, practically anything is possible. How do you know the difference between links? Also, the php should be called each time the page is loaded, unless it's called via AJAX, in which case, it will be called each time the AJAX is executed. In either case, you should have something that will tell you which DB to connect to. Just write a function in connect.php that you call with some value to tell it which to which DB it is to connect.

Comment: After looking at the code a bit closer, it seems a bit convoluted. It appears you just try to connect to whatever doesn't fail, wiping out the connection and not using it in the main code. It looks a bit like a recipe for trouble. Surely you know what page (link) is calling it, and what db it should connect to. Even if you grab the url to get the link, there needs to be some thought and control build into the code so a page doesn't connect to the wrong DB. That's a huge security risk IMHO.

Comment: Only call the connection once. Assign the variables based on the host. `switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'example1.com' : $db_user = 'db1; $db_pass = '1'; etc. break; } $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);` If this is an attempt at loading balancing please clarify that, this is not what this comment is about.